# Ubuntu 20.04 stuck on file system check

Tags: 20.04

So recently I installed Ubuntu 20.04. Everything seemed to work fine, but as soon as I rebooted the system it got stuck on file system check and I can't even load from a live USB, it just goes straight to this check! Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Not relay helpful, but this is just another reported problem with 20.xx that makes me stay on my 18.xx.

Comment: @Aika Sat, pls. give details about the boot mode setting in the UEFI/BIOS (legacy or UEFI mode?). Knowing if there is an SSD involved, and the location of the boot loader you've chosen during the installation (disk, partition, both?) may enable others to help.